# How can I access my Ubuntu boot disk files as external USB disk on Centos 6.3?

Tags: 12.04, usb, lvm, drive

Not sure whether this would be more appropriate in a Centos forum, but I'll post it here for starters as I am more comfortable and familiar with Ubuntu. I recently purchased a server with Centos 6.3 already on it. I want to copy some files from my Ubuntu Server 12.04 drive as an external USB drive. It immediately comes up as a drive in Centos, but it only shows a GRUB folder, a Lost+Found folder, and a few other files. I had LVM set up on it, but I don't see any of that.

Any suggestions? I'd like to avoid copying over the network.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much more a CentOS problem - to access a partition that is part of a LVM setup the receiving system must have LVM installed (about which I can't tell you anything).

From here the steps are the same on every system:

You can see what is there with `sudo pvdisplay` (to see physical volumes), `sudo vgdisplay` (for volume groups) and `sudo lvdisplay` for logical volumes -- all three for checking only.

You then must activate all LVs with `sudo vgchange -a` and will now be able to mount any LV you want.